# Unsupported Image format in Open3D create Pointcloud from RGBD Image

Tags: python, image, 3d, open3d

I am loading a RGB-Image using PIL and then process the Image to a numpy array in order to create the Pointcloud from RGBD Image, the depth map is processed successfully by using the GLPN-Transformer Depth Estimation model. I process both the depth map and the input image into a open3.geometry.Image() dtype. However, I get following error:

```
    rgbd_image = o3d.geometry.RGBDImage.create_from_color_and_depth(image_3d, depth_3d, convert_rgb_to_intensity=False)
RuntimeError: [Open3D Error] (class std::shared_ptr<class open3d::geometry::RGBDImage> __cdecl open3d::geometry::RGBDImage::CreateFromColorAndDepth(const class open3d::geometry::Image &,const class open3d::geometry::Image &,double,double,bool)) D:\a\Open3D\Open3D\cpp\open3d\geometry\RGBDImageFactory.cpp:21: Unsupported image format.
```

It says its an unsupported Image format, however, `create_from_color_and_depth`required o3d.geometry.Image as datatype

Full Code:

```py
import cv2
import torch
import open3d as o3d 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from transformers import GLPNImageProcessor, GLPNForDepthEstimation
from PIL import Image

def LoadImageCV(input_path):
    input_image = cv2.imread(input_path)
    input_image = cv2.resize(input_image, (1000, 1000), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return cv2.cvtColor(input_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

def LoadImagePIL(input_path):
    input_image = Image.open(input_path)
    return input_image.resize((1000, 1000))

def DisplayImage(input, colormap):
    plt.imshow(input, cmap=colormap)
    plt.show()

def GenerateDepthMap(input_image):
    # load image processing and depth estimation models
    feature_extractor = GLPNImageProcessor.from_pretrained("vinvino02/glpn-nyu")
    model = GLPNForDepthEstimation.from_pretrained("vinvino02/glpn-nyu")

    inputs = feature_extractor(images=input_image, return_tensors="pt")

    # get predictions
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        predicted_depth = outputs.predicted_depth

    # process output into optimal sizes
    padding = 16
    output = predicted_depth.squeeze().cpu().numpy() * 1000.0
    output = output[padding:-padding, padding:-padding]

    return output

def GeneratePointcloud3D(input_image, depth_map):
    # get sizes of input image and convert to numpy array for processing
    width, height = input_image.size
    input_image = np.array(input_image)

    # process depth map
    depth_map = (depth_map * 255 / np.max(depth_map)).astype("uint8")

    depth_3d = o3d.geometry.Image(depth_map)
    image_3d = o3d.geometry.Image(input_image)
    rgbd_image = o3d.geometry.RGBDImage.create_from_color_and_depth(image_3d, depth_3d, convert_rgb_to_intensity=False)

    # camera settings 
    camera_intrinsic = o3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsic()
    camera_intrinsic.set_intrinsic(width, height, 500, 500, width / 2, height / 2)

    # generate pointcloud 
    pointcloud = o3d.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_rgbd_image(rgbd_image, camera_intrinsic)

    return pointcloud

def GenerateMesh3D(pointcloud):
    # outliers removal
    cl, index = pointcloud.remove_statistical_outlier(nb_neighbors=20, std_ratio=20.0)
    pointcloud = pointcloud.select_by_index(index)

    # get normals from pointcloud
    pointcloud.estimate_normals()
    pointcloud.orient_normals_to_align_with_direction()

    # construct mesh
    mesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_poisson(pointcloud, depth=10, n_threads=1)[0]

    # rotate mesh
    rotation = mesh.get_rotation_matrix_from_xyz((np.pi, 0, 0))
    mesh.rotate(rotation, center=(0, 0, 0))

    return mesh

def main():
    # input image path
    INPUT_PATH = "src/Images/sample1.jpg"

    # load input image
    input_image = LoadImagePIL(INPUT_PATH)
    # input_image = LoadImageCV(INPUT_PATH)

    # get depth map
    depth_map = GenerateDepthMap(input_image)
    DisplayImage(depth_map, "plasma")

    # get Pointcloud
    pointcloud = GeneratePointcloud3D(input_image, depth_map)

    # get mesh
    mesh = GenerateMesh3D(pointcloud)

    # display pointcloud and mesh
    o3d.visualizations.draw_geometries([pointcloud])
    o3d.visualizations.draw_geometries([mesh], mesh_show_back_face=True)

    cv2.waitKey(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

### Main Issue

Resolution of color and depth image do not match. See Open3D code [here](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/blob/3d27acce3c76a71515457a54b01afb2af0de0d1a/cpp/open3d/geometry/RGBDImageFactory.cpp#L40).

The mismatch occurs due to model output not having same dimensions as color image and furthermore another cropping done via: `output[padding:-padding, padding:-padding]` (not sure why this is needed).

You can either crop color image so that you create RGBD image where you have both color and depth values or you keep color image as it is and pad depth image with 0/infinity (whichever you prefer, note - infinity means as far away as possible).

Cropping color image:-

```
# Assuming neural network lead to loss of margin on all sides equally
p = (width - depth_map.shape[0]) // 2  # p for padding
input_image = input_image[p:-p, p:-p]
```

Padding depth image:-

```
# Assuming neural network lead to loss of margin on all sides equally
p = padding = (width - depth_map.shape[0]) // 2  # p for padding
depth_map = np.pad(depth_map, [(p, p), (p, p)], mode="constant", constant_values=0)
```

### Other minor bugs:

1. Remove `set_intrinsic` and use right constructor.

`camera_intrinsic = o3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsic(width, height, 500, 500, width / 2, height / 2)`

2. Fix `o3d.visualization` package name. No `s` in `visualization`.
3. Ensure numpy array is **contiguous** before mapping to o3d Image type.

```
depth_3d = o3d.geometry.Image(np.ascontiguousarray(depth_map))
```

4. Depth map scaling into Image

Dont see why `depth_map = (depth_map * 255 / np.max(depth_map)).astype("uint8")` is done. Open3D needs actual depth map, without any uint8 conversion.

### Full Code

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
import torch
from PIL import Image
from transformers import GLPNImageProcessor, GLPNForDepthEstimation


def LoadImageCV(input_path):
    input_image = cv2.imread(input_path)
    input_image = cv2.resize(input_image, (1000, 1000), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return cv2.cvtColor(input_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


def LoadImagePIL(input_path):
    input_image = Image.open(input_path)
    return input_image.resize((1000, 1000))


def DisplayImage(input, colormap=None):
    plt.imshow(input, cmap=colormap)
    plt.show()


def GenerateDepthMap(input_image):
    # load image processing and depth estimation models
    feature_extractor = GLPNImageProcessor.from_pretrained("vinvino02/glpn-nyu")
    model = GLPNForDepthEstimation.from_pretrained("vinvino02/glpn-nyu")

    inputs = feature_extractor(images=input_image, return_tensors="pt")

    # get predictions
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        predicted_depth = outputs.predicted_depth

    # process output into optimal sizes
    padding = 16
    output = predicted_depth.squeeze().cpu().numpy() * 1000.0
    output = output[padding:-padding, padding:-padding]

    return output


def generate_pointcloud_3D(input_image, depth_map):
    # get sizes of input image and convert to numpy array for processing
    width, height = input_image.size
    input_image = np.array(input_image)

    # process depth map
    # Assuming neural network lead to loss of margin on all sides equally
    p = (width - depth_map.shape[0]) // 2  # p for padding
    # depth_map = np.pad(depth_map, [(p, p), (p, p)], mode="constant", constant_values=0)

    input_image = input_image[p:-p, p:-p]

    depth_3d = o3d.geometry.Image(np.ascontiguousarray(depth_map))
    image_3d = o3d.geometry.Image(np.ascontiguousarray(input_image))
    rgbd_image = o3d.geometry.RGBDImage.create_from_color_and_depth(image_3d, depth_3d, convert_rgb_to_intensity=False)

    # camera settings
    camera_intrinsic = o3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsic(
        input_image.shape[0], input_image.shape[1], 500, 500, input_image.shape[0] / 2, input_image.shape[1] / 2
    )

    # generate pointcloud
    pointcloud = o3d.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_rgbd_image(
        rgbd_image,
        camera_intrinsic,
    )
    pointcloud.transform([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])

    return pointcloud


def GenerateMesh3D(pointcloud):
    # outliers removal
    cl, index = pointcloud.remove_statistical_outlier(nb_neighbors=20, std_ratio=20.0)
    pointcloud = pointcloud.select_by_index(index)

    # get normals from pointcloud
    pointcloud.estimate_normals()
    pointcloud.orient_normals_to_align_with_direction()

    # construct mesh
    mesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_poisson(pointcloud, depth=10, n_threads=1)[0]

    # rotate mesh
    rotation = mesh.get_rotation_matrix_from_xyz((np.pi, 0, 0))
    mesh.rotate(rotation, center=(0, 0, 0))

    return mesh


def main():
    # input image path
    INPUT_PATH = "data/2023-03-13_14-07-39/image/00000.jpg"

    # load input image
    input_image = LoadImagePIL(INPUT_PATH)
    DisplayImage(input_image.copy(), colormap=None)

    # get depth map
    depth_map = GenerateDepthMap(input_image)
    DisplayImage(depth_map.copy(), colormap="plasma")

    # get Pointcloud
    pointcloud = generate_pointcloud_3D(input_image, depth_map)

    # get mesh
    mesh = GenerateMesh3D(pointcloud)

    # display pointcloud and mesh
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pointcloud])
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([mesh], mesh_show_back_face=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result:-

[image: Mesh for image of chair and a whiteboard]